# Reference: Hardy space regularity of the Jacobian determinant

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I'm looking for a reference, expository in nature, for the proof of the following theorem of Coifman, Lions, Meyer and Semmes.

Theorem:

For all $u\in W^{1,n}(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)$, $\operatorname*{det}Du\in\mathcal{H}^1(\mathbb{R}^n).$

While I have the paper of Coifman, Lions, Meyer and Semmes where the result was proved, I'm looking for something that is more expository in nature, preferably lecture notes or books where the result was discussed and proved in detail.

Thank you.

Stefan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Lion's own exposition: [Jacobians and Hardy spaces](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1301&context=math).

> The present report gives some elementary proofs, explained in the
>   simple solution of $R^2$, of the embedding results of Jacobian
>   determinants into Hardy spaces.